# Backbone global success handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, backbone.js

In our project we use backbone to access a REST service.
This service delivers an HTTP Header that contains a kind of session token to authenticate the current user.
This token changes on every request.

We use this token with our Login Model to determine if a login is need on the current route.

The first idea was using jQuery.ajaxSuccess.

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    updateToken(xhr);
});
```

Works nearly but the global success is triggered after the success handlers in backbone.
So if any backbone success handler starts a new request to the server, it has an old token at this moment and the request will be rejected.

Call updateToken in every success handler or continuing processing using setTimeout is to much effort and error prone. it may be forgotten.

Now we created this solution

```
var BBsync = Backbone.sync;
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
    var success = options.success;
    options.success = function(model, response, options) {
        updateToken(options);
        success(model, response, options);
    };
    return BBsync.call(this, method, model, options);
};
```

All success methods are wrapped.
Is there any risk in this solution?
Have we overlooked something?
Any better solutions?

Comment: Seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that your approach works as we do the same thing for the same reason.